# Как сделать виджет вк адаптивным по ВЫСОТЕ и ширине?

Tags: вконтакте

Нужно сделать адаптивным не только по ширине виджет группы, но и по высоте для мобильных устройств разной ширины. По ширине все работает корректно, но если такие же методы использовать в высоте они не работают.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] — тот он должен быть в высоту слайдера.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] - тут тоже тоже нужно что бы он ссузился по ширине блока
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] - на компах он выглядит корректно

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//vk.com/js/api/openapi.js?152"></script>

<!-- VK Widget -->
<div id="vk_groups"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
VK.Widgets.Group("vk_groups", {mode: 3}, 157152322);
</script>
```

Comment: и как без кода вам помочь?))

Comment: Добавил код, простите